# RestKit copySeedDatabaseIfNecessaryFromPath: database empty

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to create a persistent store using a seed database calling the following method

```
- (NSPersistentStore *)addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:(NSString *)storePath
                           fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:(NSString *)seedPath
                                withConfiguration:(NSString *)nilOrConfigurationName
                                          options:(NSDictionary *)nilOrOptions
                                            error:(NSError **)error
```

The database is correctly created but is empty. I have checked that the seed database has data.

For a full process description, you can check the following SO question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301227/how-to-perform-persistent-store-swap-with-restkit-0-2

Comment: Do you get any error logged? Show the code you're using and how you're testing.

Comment: I have a bit modified the way i do it by altering the - (BOOL)resetPersistentStores:(NSError **)error in RKManagedObjectStore. Because RestKit 0.2 use the seedPath from  [persistentStore.options valueForKey:RKSQLitePersistentStoreSeedDatabasePathOption]; to recreate the persistent store. Now i'm able to create the database with all data but i got the following error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'